Eclipse IDE won't run / compile any java code on Debian 12
I recently installed Eclipse on my Debian machine and installed a JDK (22 to be specific). Whenever I try to run anything I get this error:
Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
The code is a simple hello world print, so I know for sure the syntax is not the problem, since I've written it by hand and copied it and the same error occurs, so I'm fairly certain I did something wrong while making the project file or installing the IDE/JDK.
In case I've made a mistake, this is the code I'm trying to run:
package bunajava;

public class HelloJava {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello Java");
    }
}

I've tried changing the class name to the module name, and that solved part of the problem, now I only have this issue, and I couldn't find anything on here...
I've also got more errors relating to file paths, though I couldn't understand them..
Here is one of the errors:
/home/manole/Documents/SDK/jdk-23_linux-aarch64_bin/jdk-23/bin/java: 1: �h�������������: not found.
I'm new to java and I have no idea what the problem could be..
Thanks in advance.

I strongly recommend that (at your stage of the game at least) that you always use your package manager to install Java.

Which version of Eclipse is this, and how was it installed? Where is that error text appearing? Which font are you using there (it's not uncommon for characters that can't be rendered using a particular font to end up looking like that)? How are you running your code--what steps are you performing?

I'm using Eclipse 2024-09 (release 4.33), and I installed it from their website. The error was appearing after I ran the code, and the steps were the usual: create a project, create a package, write code and run. At least that's what I did, I'm not certain it is correct. Regarding @JJF 's comment, I'm using Eclipse because that's what the university wants us to use, I too would have preferred IDEA or VSCode.

If you have a module-info.java file, delete it (if needed you can recreate it later via right-clicking on the project folder and choosing Configure). In Run > Run Configurations... also delete your run configuration(s). Then try again.

"Installed it from their website" could use some elaboration, and literally, what button or menu option or command are you using to Run your application? Also, are you actually on an aarch64 system like a Raspberry Pi or an ARM Chromebook? Otherwise that's the wrong architecture for the Java installation. Have you tried changing the Console font on the Colors and Fonts preference page?

@howlger That was the first thing I did, it had a different issue regarding the main(String[] args). It gave the error "This selection cannot be launched and there are no recent launches" so I deleted module-info.java and set the filename the same as the class name, and that error got replaced with this one.

@nitind I'm pressing 'Run as' and then 'Java Application'. Also, no. I am not on a aarch64 system and it doesn't make sense since I installed the x86_64 version. Should I reinstall using a package manager or is this fixable without uninstalling?

What @nitind says. aarch64 in the path /home/manole/Documents/SDK/jdk-23_linux-aarch64_bin/jdk-23/bin/java indicates that you try to run your code with Java 23 for ARM which will not work on a x86_64 system (and by the way, it seems to be a Java 23, not a Java 22 JDK). What do you have in Window > Preferences: Java > Installed JREs? Is there a JRE/JDK that is part of your Eclipse installation? If yes, use that one (which is also used to run Eclipse).

*to a point. Any bundled JRE is there to run Eclipse, but to learn or develop in Java, you still want to get a full JDK so you have sources and access to JavaDoc.

@nitind The Java that is included in Eclipse is most likely a full JDK, at least the ZIP IDE packages contain a full JDK.

@howlger That's unexpected.

@howlger Thank you so much!!! That was my issue, I've installed the correct Eclipse IDE (x86_64) but installed the wrong JDK (aarch64). The ticked option was the JDK, I ticked the SDK and the code ran perfectly. Again, thank you so much!

Glad it works now, but @nitind was the one who spotted this first.

One more question so I know in the future: How does this work now? Does someone have to answer or do we leave the thread like this?

I certainly suspected it, hence the first comment. Acting on it would have solved the problem. It should be acted on now

@manole Someone will add an answer and then you can accept the answer as correct answer. Since nitind was the first one who mentioned aarch64, I think that nitind should be the one to answer and get the reputation points. Unfortunately, only one person can be the author of an answer, even if others have contributed to the solution.

@howlger I agree, nitind should post the answer. Thank you everyone for the help!

Ok, I'm adding one. Did you sort out the font problem? Even italics can cause a font to be unrenderable.

The problem with the fonts is that they weren't all rhombuses with question marks in them or even italic, I don't think stack overflow knows those characters.. in the IDE they were many and varied. I think i even saw squares once :)) It was weird but I don't think it was a font problem, but a wrong architecture problem.. I could be wrong though.

An aarch64 system would be something like a Raspberry Pi or an ARM Chromebook, meaning that's the wrong architecture for a Java installation on most conventional Linux systems which are now x86-64. Aarch64 binaries can't be run on x86/x86-64 systems without significant and intentional steps for emulation. You need a x86-64 Java runtime instead, and to make sure that's what your Installed JREs preference page includes and your project refers to. Then the java executable within it will be runnable and able to run your application.

sudo apt update followed by apt-cache search jdk are your friends. Debian is optimized for stability, not cutting edge software, so don't expect to find the latest jdk there. You almost certainly don't need it anyway at this stage. Later you might add the Bellsoft java repos to apt
